# Is it possible to stop a service through launchd if the service is started manually?

Tags: macos, services, launchd, launchctl

I am using launchd to start mysql on boot, it is working fine. I am able to stop and start the service using 'launchctl unload' and 'launchctl load' commands. Also I am able to start the service by typing 'mysqld_safe' command in terminal. But, if I stop the service through 'launchctl stop' and then start the service through 'mysqld_safe' command, I am unable to stop the service through 'launchctl stop'. Is this possible? What I am doing wrong here?

My Plist is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>mysql.service</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/path/to/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
                <string>--defaults-file=/path/to/mysql/my.cnf</string>
                <string>--port=3306</string>
                <string>--socket=/path/to/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock</string>
                <string>--datadir=/path/to/mysql/data</string>
                <string>--log-error=/path/to/mysql/data/mysqld.log</string>
                <string>--pid-file=/path/to/mysql/data/mysqld.pid</string>
       </array>
       <key>RunAtLoad</key>
       <true/>
       <key>KeepAlive</key>
       <false/>
       <key>UserName</key>
       <string>_mysql</string>
       <key>GroupName</key>
       <string>_mysql</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/mysql_start.out</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/mysql_start.err</string>

</dict>
</plist>
```

Command used to start mysql through terminal is:

```
mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/path/to/mysql/my.cnf --port=3306 --socket=/path/to/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock --datadir=/path/to/mysql/data --pid-file=/path/to/mysql/data/mysqld.pid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intended behavior. Issuing `launchctl stop` for a job which has not been loaded does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following line:

```
<key>ExitTimeOut</key>       <integer>30</integer>
```

If you tail the error_log you'll see that nothing happens until after this timeout. You could make this value smaller.

You will something like the following

```
2016-09-13 13:42:09 14055 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2016-09-13 13:42:09 14055 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2016-09-13 13:42:09 14055 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2016-09-13 13:42:09 14055 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
...
2016-09-13 13:42:10 14055 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2016-09-13 13:42:10 14055 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2016-09-13 13:42:10 14055 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2016-09-13 13:42:10 14055 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2016-09-13 13:42:10 14055 [Note] /usr/local/mysql-5.6.33-osx10.11-x86_64/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Why things do not die gracefully before the timeout value - I do not know but I have been using this and it's compatible  with the mysql.server start/stop commands as well.